# How to determine structure group of a fiber bundle intrinsically from its topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I've been reviewing fiber bundles from the nitty-gritty standpoint of atlases and want an intrinsic definition of the structure group based solely on the topology of the bundle $(E,B,\pi)$.  Steenrod includes a top group action in the def of a fiber bundle, thus imposing it externally.  Some other authors define a fiber bundle as taking *any* open cover of charts, but then ignore the question altogether.

If we start with a bundle $(E,B,\pi)$ which admits some atlas (and thus has homeomorphic fibers), there should be an intrinsic structure group that reflects how fibers topologically twist as we move around $B$.  I.e. we shouldn't need to be told to confine ourselves to atlases with overlap $g_{ij}$'s in some external $G$.  I'll use the term "atlas" in this question to refer to one relative to $Homeo(F)$ as a whole (i.e. no $G$-restriction on the overlaps).

The topology of $E$ dictates the set of open subsets $U\subset B$ which appear in charts, but any given $U$ has a vast number of associated charts.  Ex. given any $\psi:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times F$ and any $\lambda\in Homeo(F)$, we can construct another chart with the same $U$ and $\psi'= (Id_U,\lambda)\circ\psi$.  In fact, we can compose with any continuous fn $\lambda':U\rightarrow Homeo(F)$.  Similarly, given an atlas, we can obtain another by composing $\lambda$ across the board (or composing each chart with a fn $\lambda'_i$ as above).

Given any atlas, the topology of the bundle manifests in the overlap $g_{ij}$'s.  Atlas $A$ has associated group $G(A)$ generated by those $g_{ij}$'s (i.e. the homeomorphism on $F$ at each point in $U_i\cap U_j$) induced by the overlap maps.

An atlas $A$ has the property of being "maximal" if no new charts can be added relative to its own $G(A)$.  It is maximal only relative to that group, and in fact manifests (in some overlap map) every element of $G(A)$.  Every atlas $A$ has a unique maximal atlas $\hat{A}$ which has $G(\hat{A})= G(A)$.  An atlas is "minimal" if we can't remove a single chart without ceasing to be a cover of $B$.

There exist atlases (and minimal atlases) which have varying groups $G(A)$.  Consider the Mobius strip $M$, with $B=S^1$ and $F=I$.  There are atlases with $4$ charts whose $U$'s cover a little over a quarter of the circle each and whose overlap $g_{ij}$'s happen to be constant.  If we denote $i$ the flip map $t\rightarrow 1-t$, $e= Id_F$, and $x$ some other homeomorphism on $F$ (ex. $t\rightarrow t^2$), the ops $(e,i,x)$ generate some group $H\subset Homeo(F)$.  There are minimal atlases of the type described with the following values (among others) for the overlap $g$'s:  $[e,i,e,e]$, $[i,i,i,e]$, $[e,xix^{-1},e,e]$.

The question is how do we intrinsically (i.e. without being told $G$) identify that $(e,i)\approx Z_2$ is the correct structure group of the bundle $(M,S^1,\pi)$?

There are two possibilities which leap out at me, and I don't know which (if either) is the case or how to prove them.  The idea is that either there is

1. (Possibility 1):  A unique (modulo inner-automorphism of $Homeo(F)$) largest subgroup $H\subset Homeo(F)$ s.t. for every minimal atlas $A$, $G(A)$ contains $H$ modulo an inner-automorphism of $Homeo(F)$ (i.e. $H\subseteq \lambda G(A)\lambda^{-1}$ for some $\lambda\in Homeo(F)$).

or

2. (Possibility 2):  A unique (modulo inner-automorphism of $Homeo(F)$) smallest subgroup $H\subset Homeo(F)$ s.t. every maximal atlas has some minimal atlas with $H=G(A)$ modulo an inner automorphism (i.e. $H= \lambda G(A)\lambda^{-1}$ for some $\lambda\in Homeo(F)$).

My take is that we at least need the "modulo an inner-automorphism" due to the $\lambda$-flexibility above, and that the best we can do is narrow down the structure group to a class of groups related by inner-automorphisms of $Homeo(F)$.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any insight into how we would determine the appropriate structure group intrinsically from the basic bundle topology and whether anyone has a simple proof (or counterexample) for either of these two possibilities.

Cheers,
Ken

Comment: Well, (I think) yes and no.   Any given maximal atlas relative to some chosen group action does give you additional structure (a choice of local coords at each point s.t. in the overlaps they are related a certain way).  However, this does not mean there isn't a notion of group intrinsic the topology.  If you traverse the base space via any atlas relative to any suitable (i.e. containing $(e,i)$ group, the net effect of all overlaps has to be $i$ (a single inversion of the fiber).   Intuitively,  the structure group is $Z_2$ --- and this is not dependent on atlas (we can pick a bigger one).

Comment: Of course, I may be way off-base about this.   If you tell me that $Z_2$ has nothing to do intrinsically with the Mobius strip and just comes from a choice of atlas on it, that's certainly possible.  But we can just as well choose an atlas with $Z_2$ for the cylinder $I\times S^1$.   It would have an even number of twists (ex. $[e,i,i,e]$ in my example).   The fact that $Z_2$ is associated with $M$ and $\{e\}$ is associated with $I\times S^1$ should come (I think) directly from their topology.  We have too much freedom to pick atlases with other groups.

Comment: [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244581) is somewhat related.

Comment: @Karl  Interesting. It seems the technical way to describe what I'm trying to do is "reduction of the structure group" from $Homeo(I)$ to $Z_2$, and it sounds like it requires some heavier duty AT.  In fact, I'm having a very hard time finding any treatment of the topic for general fiber bundles (as opposed to principal bundles such as frame bundles).    I'd wager that if one of my two guesses happens to be correct, it will be highly nontrivial to prove.   Thanks for the link; now I at least know what to search for.

Comment: I think they're using the "reduction" terminology informally. We know what it means to be *a* structure group of the bundle, but I'm curious how one actually defines the "smallest" one. (Am I missing something obvious?) Maybe one of your guesses *is* the right definition.

Comment: @Karl  It actually seems to be a standard term.  https://planetmath.org/reductionofstructuregroup has a def, but no indication how to actually determine what reductions exist.  They say their def is tantamount to demanding that *some* atlas (aka local trivialization) has the relevant smaller group as its $g_{ij}$'s.  However, their def doesn't tell us whether there is a unique such minimal group or (if not) whether they're all related by inner-automorphisms.   As their def is stated, it appears to allow both such possibilities (among others).

Comment: You are right that these things are generally very nontrivial to prove. There is a strategy which you can employ when you wish to show every bundle with structure group $G$ has a reduction to one with structure group $H$, and that is to show the inclusion $H \leq G$ is actually a homotopy equivalence. This will imply every $G$ bundle has an essentially unique reduction to an $H$ bundle. An example of this is that every $\mathbb{R}^n$ bundle with structure group $\mathrm{Diff}(n)$ actually has a reduction to a vector bundle.

Comment: When $H \leq G$ is not a homotopy equivalence, you can still try to understand reductions by understanding the homotopy classes of maps from the base to $G/H$, but the techniques will start to be much more ad hoc.

Comment: @Connor  Wow, I never would have guessed it would be based on homotopy!   But I think I'm misunderstanding the details of your reply.  It seems what you're describing relies only on the topological relationship between $H\subseteq G\subseteq Homeo(F)$ (basically, whether $H$ has holes relative to $G$) and makes no ref to the top of $E$.    Is this method just for principal bundles or do you mean something different by the inclusion $H\le G$ being a homotopy equivalence?  The way I'm reading it, $S^1\times I$ and the Mobius strip would end up with the same maximally-reduced structure group.

Comment: @Connor  Or is is that since $\{e\}\subset Z_2$ is not a homotopy equiv, we would need the "ad hoc" methods, which would work for $S^1\times I$ but not for the Mobius strip?  Even so, I would find it very counterintuitive for such a powerful general result (in the case of $H\le G$ being a homotopy equivalence) to exist independent of any topological details of $E$ (other than a choice of fiber that admits a suitable $Homeo(F)$, of course).  BTW, do you happen to know a good treatment of this approach?  I couldn't find anything online but don't know the right terms to search for.

Comment: The set of principal $G$-bundles is actually in natural bijection with $F$-bundles with structure group $G$. The "reason" behind all this is because classifying spaces exist for principal $G$-bundles, meaning homotopy classes of maps into them are equivalent to isomorphism classes of bundles. I believe Kirk and Davis's notes cover all of this stuff to some extent.

Comment: @Connor  Now that you mention it, that makes complete sense.   After all, if we pick a system of coordinate transforms on the base space, then the twisting will be same on all the fiber bundles we build by picking different (suitable) fibers.   So we really need only study the twisting of principal bundles, after all.   Thank you very much for your help and for the reference!  If you copy your comments into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a $G$-space. It is a classical that isomorphism classes of $F$-bundles with structure group $G$ are in correspondence with principal $G$-bundles, so one can often restrict their attention to principal $G$-bundles. Principal $G$-bundles are classified by homotopy classes of maps into a space called $BG$ which is characterized by i) being connected and ii) having an equivalence $\Omega BG \simeq G$.

In terms of principal bundles, the question of reducing the structure group from $G$ to $H \leq G$ is equivalent to asking what the image of $[X,BH] \rightarrow [X,BG]$ is. As one might imagine, this is a difficult question in general. One case in which it is approachable is if one can argue that $BH \rightarrow BG$ is a homotopy equivalence. This happens, if and only if, the inclusion $H \leq G$ is a homotopy equivalence of spaces. This happens a lot in practice, notably, for the chain of inclusions $O(n) \leq GL(n) \leq \mathrm{Diff}(n)$, but not for the "inclusion" $\mathrm{Diff}(n) \leq \mathrm{Homeo}(n)$. I write "inclusion" here because there are subtle issues with the topologies involved.

If one is dealing with an inclusion that is not a homotopy equivalence, one could start by understanding $\mathrm{hofiber}(BH \rightarrow BG)$. From ii) it is fairly straightforward to show $\mathrm{hofiber}(BH \rightarrow BG) \simeq G/H$, at least when their is nothing weird going on with the topologies of the groups. An example of where we know this homotopy type is $\mathrm{Top}(n)/ PL(n)$ when $n\geq 4$. It has the homotopy type of $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,3)$. This calculation is the fundamental calculation in Triangulation theory which characterizes which manifolds (above dimension 4) can be made PL in terms of a single cohomology class called the Kirby–Siebenmann invariant in $H^4(M; \mathbb{Z}/2)$.

There is a lot more to be said about this question, particularly in regard to characteristic classes. These are elements in the cohomology of the classifying space $BG$, and these can be used to decide questions of structure group reduction. The most elementary example of this is that a vector bundle is orientable, if and only if, its first Stiefel-Whitney class is trivial. For an introduction to characteristic classes of vector bundles, I highly recommend Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration!  This is a really informative overview.  I remember glancing at Milnor's book a long time ago as part of an AT course and now have a good motive to properly revisit it.   You've given me a pretty clear picture of what I need to look at.